# Issue with multiple select in LINQ Method query

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have this TSQL:

```
SELECT 'Outdoor Tournaments' AS Name, COUNT(a.location) AS Value
FROM
(select location
from [dbo].[TournamentBatchItem]
GROUP BY TournamentName, location) a
WHERE a.location = 'Outdoor'

UNION

SELECT 'Indoor Tournaments' AS Name, COUNT(a.location) AS Value
FROM
(select location
from [dbo].[TournamentBatchItem]
GROUP BY TournamentName, location) a
WHERE a.location = 'Indoor'
```

The initial solution for LINQ Method:

```
var tournamentStats1 = await _context.TournamentBatchItem.Where(t => t.Location == "Outdoor" || t.Location == "Indoor")
                          .GroupBy(t => t.Location)                                        
                          .Select(t => new { Name = t.Key, Value = t.Location})
                          .ToListAsync();
```

Then we realise that is not the right one and we modified into this and tested **LinqPAD** app and worked OK:

```
var tournamentStats1 = await _context.TournamentBatchItem.Where(t => t.Location == "Outdoor" || t.Location == "Indoor")
                          .GroupBy(t => new { t.TournamentName, t.Location })
                          .Select(t => new { Name = t.Key.TournamentName, Value = t.Key.Location })
                          .GroupBy(a => a.Value)
                          .Select(a => new Stat { Name = a.Key, Value=a.Count() })
                          .ToList();
```

However, when we put into .Net Core 2.1 web app and we have this "System.ArgumentException: must be reducible node" and it looks something to do with nested Select so we modified this into below by splitting the query. This one worked OK.

```
var tournamentStats1 = await _context.TournamentBatchItem.Where(t => t.Location == "Outdoor" || t.Location == "Indoor")
                                    .GroupBy(t => new { t.TournamentName, t.Location })
                                    .Select(t => new { Name = t.Key.TournamentName, Value = t.Key.Location })
                                    .ToListAsync();


            var tournamentStats = tournamentStats1.GroupBy(a => a.Value)
                                    .Select(a => new Stat { Name = a.Key, Value=a.Count() })
                                    .ToList();
```

Is this a bug? Does anyone have an experience on this 2.1 version?

Thanks

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? EF Core?

Comment: We implemented EF core